# yii2 login user manually with getting user and password from ajax

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i send mobile number as username and active_code as password from view file([ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)) to action with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)and i want login user with this data.

This code is my action:

```
//if entered information is correct then do:
$identity = \common\models\User::findOne(["username"=>$mobile]);
if(Yii::$app->user->login($identity))
   return 100;
else
   return 500;
```

It is worked(`return 100`) but after page refreshed, it seems user not logged in!
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try to see in debug mode if session or cookie login are set